# Italic Overwrites Standard?

Tags: css, fonts

I'm trying to declare various forms of the same font in my project. I want a `normal` and `italic` version of each font type under the same *BrandonText* name. As soon as I add the `italic` version in, the `normal` version is completely ignored.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'BrandonText';
    src:  url('/fonts/BrandonText-Thin.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
          url('/fonts/BrandonText-Thin.otf')  format('opentype'),
          url('/fonts/BrandonText-Thin.woff') format('woff'),
          url('/fonts/BrandonText-Thin.ttf')  format('truetype'),
          url('/fonts/BrandonText-Thin.svg#BrandonText-Thin') format('svg');
    font-weight: 100;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'BrandonText';
    src:  url('/fonts/BrandonText-Thin.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
          url('/fonts/BrandonText-Thin.otf')  format('opentype'),
          url('/fonts/BrandonText-Thin.woff') format('woff'),
          url('/fonts/BrandonText-Thin.ttf')  format('truetype'),
          url('/fonts/BrandonText-Thin.svg#BrandonText-Thin') format('svg');
    font-weight: 100;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

Why is this, and is there any way to work around this?

Comment: What gets ignored, where?

Comment: @CBroe In my site, every font that uses "BrandonText" (which will be everywhere) is italic, regardless of what is declared in the CSS for the site component. I want to be able to declare multiple weights/styles under one font name.

Comment: @CBroe I think he means all his copy is now italic.

Comment: Did you properly define font-weight and style for those elements as well?

Comment: Why are you using the same font for italics anyway - you’re aware that will give you “faux italics” only? You should rather use the proper italic variant of the font.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overriding your normal `@font-face` by italic. Instead, just declare it once:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'BrandonText';
    src:  url('/fonts/BrandonText-Thin.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
          url('/fonts/BrandonText-Thin.otf')  format('opentype'),
          url('/fonts/BrandonText-Thin.woff') format('woff'),
          url('/fonts/BrandonText-Thin.ttf')  format('truetype'),
          url('/fonts/BrandonText-Thin.svg#BrandonText-Thin') format('svg');
    font-weight: 100;
}
```

Then you can use same declaration for both cases. When you want italic, just add `font-style: italic` to element's css.

Answer (score 1):

You have given both fonts the same name. Change to this.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'BrandonText';
    src:  url('/fonts/BrandonText-Thin.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
          url('/fonts/BrandonText-Thin.otf')  format('opentype'),
          url('/fonts/BrandonText-Thin.woff') format('woff'),
          url('/fonts/BrandonText-Thin.ttf')  format('truetype'),
          url('/fonts/BrandonText-Thin.svg#BrandonText-Thin') format('svg');
    font-weight: 100;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'BrandonTextItalic';
    src:  url('/fonts/BrandonText-Thin.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
          url('/fonts/BrandonText-Thin.otf')  format('opentype'),
          url('/fonts/BrandonText-Thin.woff') format('woff'),
          url('/fonts/BrandonText-Thin.ttf')  format('truetype'),
          url('/fonts/BrandonText-Thin.svg#BrandonText-Thin') format('svg');
    font-weight: 100;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Both are declared with the same name

Change your second font-family: 'BrandonText'; to font-family: 'BrandonTextItalic';